WiFi device becomes unavailable on Lenovo Ideapad with RTL8852BE
I have a Lenovo Ideapad Slim3 16ABR8 with a RTL 8852BE network card and Ubuntu 24.04.
After booting, all WiFi networks disappear from the system after a random amount of time (sometimes immediately, sometimes after a few hours).
Here's the wireless-info for the system shortly after booting while WiFi is working;
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/N68vSRQyJd/
This is wireless-info after the wifi device disconnects;
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/NtY763V5c6/
and after attempting
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager

the device becomes unavailable;
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/nwC5QNPphm/
I've applied the changes to the kernel module parameters described in the Arch wiki for this device but nothing seems to have changed. I'd appreciate any tips on what could be going wrong and how to figure it out.

As Arch if not Ubuntu maybe following that wiki was not the best idea?

@DavidDE The issue had been occurring before I followed the Arch wiki.
